# Getting locations within radius using hibernate @query

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to get locations within radius using hibernates @query parameter.

```
@Query("SELECT id, (6371 * acos (cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(:longitude))  + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM gang HAVING distance < :distance ORDER BY distance)")
List<Long> findNearbyGangs(@Param("latitude") double lat, @Param("longitude") double lng, @Param("distance") double distance);
```

but I get the following error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Long> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.example.Gang>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having, is that you are trying to fetch the data from your query into a list of `Long`, when in fact you need a list of `Object`. This is due to the fact you fetching more than one value per row (id and distance). Change your code for the following and it should work.

```
@Query("SELECT id, (6371 * acos (cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(:longitude))  + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM gang HAVING distance < :distance ORDER BY distance)")
List<Object> findNearbyGangs(@Param("latitude") double lat, @Param("longitude") double lng, @Param("distance") double distance);
```

Comment: This doesn;t compile

Answer (score 0):

As your method name `findNearbyGangs` tells that it will return nearby gangs(List of Gang entity) but you are returning `List<Long>` which is wrong return type for the query.

**Try returning `List<Gang>` instead.**